# Not so tricky complex integral inequality

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I want to prove that 
$$
\bigg| \int_\gamma f(z)\,dz \bigg| \leq \frac{3}{4} \log2
$$
where $f(z)=\sin z$ and $\gamma$ is the imaginary axis from the origin to $i\log 2$.

So my train of thought goes as follow:

There is a theorem stating the dollowing:

If $|f(\gamma(t))| \leq M$ for every $t \in [a,b]$ we got $|\int_\gamma f | \leq M l(\gamma)$ where $l(\gamma)$ is the length  of the curve $\gamma$

So applying this to the main statement we need to show the hypotheses are satisfied.

First, it is obvious that $l(\gamma)=\log2$ since the curve in this problem is the curve $\gamma(t)=0+it\log2$.

Next, $f(\gamma(t))$ in our case is $\sin(it\log2)$ so how does it happen that $|\sin(it\log2)| \leq \frac{3}{4}$?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Taking the parametrization $\gamma(t) = it$, $0 \le t \le \log 2$ will be slightly less typing, so I'm choosing that one.

Then $\sin(it) = \frac{\exp(-t)-\exp(t)}{2i} = i \sinh t$. In particular, $|\sin(it)| = |\sinh t|$, and you can check that $\sinh$ is *increasing* on $t > 0$. Hence, for $0 \le t \le \log 2$:
$$
|\sin(it)| \le |\sin(i\log 2)| = \bigg|\frac{\exp(-\log 2)-\exp(\log 2)}{2i}\bigg| = \bigg|\frac{\frac12-2}{2}\bigg| = \frac34.
$$